# Guardar datos de un TextBox a un ListView C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un textBox que agrega correos electrónicos, cuando yo le doy al botón "Add" tendría que enviar ese texto que tengo en el textBox y cada vez que coloque un correo nuevo que siga almacenandose, pero en el ListView no se ve lo que se guarda, pero si se está guardando:

codigo del botón añadir:

```
Regex emailexp = new Regex (@"^[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~])*@[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+$");
            if (emailexp.IsMatch(txtCustomerEmail.Text))
            {
                if (txtCustomerEmail.Text != null)
                {
                    EmailListView.Items.Add(txtCustomerEmail.Text);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Creo que la prueba para null no es necesario.  Si txtCustomerEmail.text es null,emailexp.IsMatch va a estar falso.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! winforms o wpf?

Comment: Ok gracias gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El listview se usa para guardar estructuras de datos jerarquicas, un ejemplo de estos es cualquier directorio en el explorador de windows, ej:

Carpeta Entretenimiento tiene dentro de ella otras carpetas

Juegos

Musica

Peliculas

y a su vez estas carpetas pueden contener otras carpetas, eso eso es una estructura en forma de arbol

Por lo que planteas en tu problema te recomiendo que uses mejor un listbox

```
listbox1.Items.Add(textbox1.Text);
```

Para borrar un elemento seria

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

Tienes que seleccionar el item con el puntero del cursor y despues dar clic en el boton borrar

Comment: Gracias amigo, funcinó perfecto, una pregunta más, para borrar un Item del ListBox, ¿Que codigo podría usar?, ejemplo, quiero borrar patito@gmail.com nada más?

Comment: Gracias Japv, una última pregunta, ya pude guardar y borrar, ahora, esos datos ya los envié a mi base de datos, y quiero que según el ID de un cliente me devuelva al ListBox los correos que ingresé previo, ¿sabes de alguna forma?

Comment: Para eso tienes que darme mas detalles sobre la estructura de la base de datos, si quieres abre otra pregunta y explicate mejor desde ahi y me avisas por aki cuando lo hagas

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404245/llenar-listbox-seg%c3%ban-combobox-c      LISTO JAPV