# Llenar ListBox según ComboBox C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un ComboBox que llama un Store Procedure de SQL, al seleccionar un ID, este me carga el nombre del cliente, si selecciono en el ComboBox IDCliente "1", automáticamente me llena el ComboBox2 "Juanita Perez", necesito que al seleccionar el ComboBox ID Cliente me cargue los correos de mi SP (RegexEmail) a mi ListBox (EmailListBox), o sea, en resumen, cuando selecciono el ID Cliente 1 me devuelva los emails de ese cliente:

SP (Stored Procedure SQL):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spg_customer]
    @IdCustomer INT
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT 
      [IdCustomer]
      ,[Name]
      ,[RegexSubject]
      ,[RegexEmail]
      ,[RegexFilename]
      ,ISNULL(COD,0) AS COD
  FROM [DeliveryBackOffice].[dbo].[Customer]
  WHERE IdCustomer = @IdCustomer

  SELECT 
       [IdVisitPointClient]
      ,[CodeOfReference] as Hermes_ID
      ,[DescriptionOfClient] as VisitPoint_Name
      ,[StatusClient]
      ,[CountryId]
      ,[VisitPointId] as Denarius_ID
      ,[CustomerID] as Customer_ID
      ,[Address]
      ,[Zone]
      ,[Town]
      ,[Department]
      ,[Phone]
  FROM [ClientsByClients].[dbo].[VisitPointClient]
  WHERE CustomerID = @IdCustomer
  ORDER BY [DescriptionOfClient] ASC
```

Código C#:

```
private void SearchCustomerByID()
        {

            if (isSearch == true)
            {
                cbCodeCustomer.Enabled = false;
                cbNameCustomer.Enabled = false;
                string strError = "";
                string selected = this.cbCodeCustomer.GetItemText(this.cbCodeCustomer.SelectedItem);
                string selectedname = this.cbNameCustomer.GetItemText(this.cbCodeCustomer.SelectedItem);
                radbtnDelete.Enabled = true;
                idCustomer = Convert.ToInt32(selected);
                var dsResult = DaoCustomer.SearchCustomer(idCustomer);
                if (dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
                {
                    Name = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    Email = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();

                    string[] emails = Email.Split('|');

                    foreach (var word in emails)
                    {
                        if (word != " " && word != null)
                        {
                            string NewEmail = word.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '^', '$' });
                            EmailListBox.Items.Add(NewEmail);
                        }
                    }

                    ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
                    header.Text = "Co";
                    header.Name = "col1";
                    //EmailListBox.Columns.Add(header);

                    //EmailListBox.Scrollable = true;
                    //EmailListBox.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
                    //EmailListBox.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

                    if (dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString() == "True")
                    {
                        cbCod.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        cbCod.SelectedValue = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cbCod.SelectedIndex = 1;
                        cbCod.SelectedValue = 1;
                    }

                    this.grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Reset();
                    this.grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.EnableFiltering = true;

                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("VisitPoint_Name", "Nombre del punto de venta", "VisitPoint_Name");
                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("Address", "Dirección", "Address");
                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("Zone", "Zona", "Zone");
                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("Town", "Ciudad", "Town");
                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("Departament", "Departamento", "Departament");
                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("Phone", "Teléfono", "Phone");
                    grdVisitPoints.Columns.Add("RegexEmail", "Email", "RegexEmail");

                    grdVisitPoints.DataSource = dsResult;
                    grdVisitPoints.DataMember = dsResult.Tables[1].TableName;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[0].IsVisible = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[1].IsVisible = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[2].IsVisible = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[3].IsVisible = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[4].IsVisible = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[5].IsVisible = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[6].ReadOnly = true;

                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.MasterTemplate.Columns[6].ReadOnly = true;

                    grdVisitPoints.AutoScroll = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.Enabled = true;
                    grdVisitPoints.Visible = true;

                    txtCodeCustomer.Enabled = false;
                    txtCustomerName.Enabled = true;
                    txtCustomerEmail.Enabled = true;
                    EmailListBox.Enabled = true;
                    cbCod.Enabled = true;
                    radbtnNew.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se pudieron cargar datos, por favor intente de nuevo o comuniquese con el administrador del sistema.", "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
```

Tengo que devolver lo que se guarda en RegexEmail  con el IdCustomer que seleccione en el primer Combobox

Comment: dame un tiempito, dentro de un rato te atiendo

Comment: Gracias amigo, también si sabes de algún LineQuery que pueda hacer un select o algo por el estilo también lo aceptaría, ya que siento que es más facil, ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola tengo estas dudas, porque en tu procedimiento almacenado tienes dos querys, desde tu código donde  llamas a tu procedimiento almacenado y actualmente con el código que haz hecho, que es lo obtienes, cual es el resultado que tienes en el listbox o donde sea que guardes los resultados de tu consulta